# Finite field as $F_p$ vector space

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I read GTM 167 Field and Galois Theory written by Morandi.In charpter 2 ,finite fields part,
author claims that a finite field $\rm F$whose $\rm{Char(F)=p}$,$\rm p$ is a prime here,can be considered as an extension field of $\rm{F_p}$.I do not totally understand this part. $F_p$ does have characteristic p. However,how could we denmostrate that $\rm{F_p}$ is contained in $\rm F$? And the rest part says that if $\rm [F:F_p]=n$,then $\rm F$ and $\rm F_p$ are isomorphic as $F_p$ vector space,which shows that $|\rm{F}|=p^n$.Why there is an isomorphism here and how could we make the conclusion that order of $\rm F$ is $\rm p^n$?
Hint is welcomed!

Comment: If $F$ has characteristic $p$ then $\{0, 1, 2,...,p-1\}$ is a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$. Here by $1$ I mean the identity of $F$, and $n=1+...+1$. (sum the identity $n$ times) I don't understand your sentence about the isomorphism, as you wrote it, that's simply wrong. ($\mathbb{F}_p$ has dimension $1$ over itself) However, try to describe the elements of $F$ if you know that it has dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. That should give you the number of elements.

Comment: @Mark thanks for your comment and I can finish my own proof with your hints.About the isomorphism part ,however , I just simply quote the author’s statements and I believed that he made some obvious mistake there.

Comment: It should state that $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{F}_p^n$ are isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

Comment: @Mark This is an **answer** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.